# Create new user on Keycloack 10.0.1 from curl command

Tags: java, curl, keycloak

Currently I try to create a user from curl command via Keycloak's Admin REST API. I can authenticate myself as an admin, I have a good answer, but when I want to create a user then we are getting error like: 548 {"error":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}

Here are my curl commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "* Request for authorization"
RESULT=`curl --data "username=rahul&password=password&grant_type=password&    client_id=admin-cli" http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token`

echo "\n"
echo "* Recovery of the token"
TOKEN=`echo $RESULT | sed 's/.*access_token":"//g' | sed 's/".*//g'`

echo "\n"
echo "* Display token"
echo $TOKEN

echo "\n"
echo " * user creation\n"
curl -v http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/demo/users -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"   --data '{"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"xyz", "email":"demo2@gmail.com", "enabled":"true"}'
```

Error logs:

```
 curl -v http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/demo/users -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"   --data '{"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"xyz", "email":"demo2@gmail.com", "enabled":"true"}'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying ::1:8080...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /auth/admin/realms/demo/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.70.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJuNGhwUUdSeUZDcmhCTzJZbWhwc0FOWG9ZY0Ztak9CMmF3Y0RPdTNNOHhRIn0.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.BP1krGeTyTVPhKY8zHCmYowNwnGWl-lgMN7XKukUjRgxl6EEJwERwtbiruX0Qv6bZOAx5VMCntcWLPQgCTFzFXJSOnqf_YLKoUEUKrB3Lp8RHgAax0daPFVp2F86cAQ4x_ExADqepcujinvi1qP-wyWidEEVq6_j6aprzLl59y8cN6mWYL2yIZ2Vb6ZnjFHLOsOo-GZBsE1t31nG8rqPscKKhGVj7SLwexnPXCATmqYW1sc6LJgUUh2zcJrI-L8hgfyTyUHrgzi5gB7YE5mRi3M1vyHfmKNSvnca-UXo7O8OHzTzTmrDQcaTrk86xaSCcL4qm-7s9xHLeYGMAqwGEQ
> Content-Length: 81
>
} [81 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 81 out of 81 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< 548{"error":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

"HTTP 401 Unauthorized" as the error message correct implies is that the request is unauthorized. This means that the authentication details in your call are incorrect.

In your request, you send the bearer prefix as "bearer";

> Content-Type: application/json
>   Authorization: bearer <>
>   Content-Length: 81

Change this to "Bearer <>" and see if it works.
Good day!